# iOS Add UITableView section programmatically and reload it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, intersection

I want to add Section to `UITableView` and Rows to this new Section
but when I did it, the app is crashed.

How can I add data to `UITableView` and reload data without use `UITableView.ReloadData()`.

Here is methods where I use it.

```
 private void AddToSection(UITableView tableView, List<TableItems> messages, bool reload = false)
  {

     foreach (var item in messages)
     {

        if (!_section.Contains(item.Section))
        {
           _sectionMessage.Add(new List<string>());
           _section.Add(item.Section);
           if (reload)
           {                  
              var index = NSIndexSet.FromIndex(_section.Count - 1);
              tableView.InsertSections(index, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);                  
           }

        }
        int section = _section.Count - 1;
        _sectionMessage[section].Add(item.Message);

        if (reload)
        {
           int row = _sectionMessage.LastOrDefault().Count-1;
           var index = new NSIndexPath[] {NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(row, section) };
           tableView.InsertRows(index, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);             
        }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit first:
You have to update your dataSource as well. You cannot just add a new section and cells to the tablView without updating your dataSource.

///
Did you try with the following?

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Often when you do reloadData() and you didn't update your dataSource correctly, you'll get problems like yours.

Comment: Yes with same result

Comment: What does the debugger say? There's not so much information...
Also, do you update your model/data source as well correctly?

Comment: This is exception:
NSRangeException Reason: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 13 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]

Comment: So this means you want to add/access an element at index 13, but your dataSource defines only elements 0 .. 12. You have to update the number of sections and number of cells in their methods as well, you cannot just add a new section or cell to the table.